# In this set of rules, is the x in s(x) identical with the x in p(x) or are these two different variables?

Tags: recursion

In this set of rules, is the x in s(x) identical with the x in p(x) or are these two different variables? I didn't find an answer and how to actually search it. [image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: Wrong forum indeed. Didn't find where to delete or move it

Comment: A llittle hard to tell, without any context, but I don't think it would make much sense for the $x$ in $s(x)$ and the $x$ in $p(x)$ to be different.